# not all duplicates being removed

Tags: python

This is a sample code I am running to remove duplicates from sorted and comma separated list.
But it is not removing some duplicates.....

```
import sys

beginning=1;
prev=0;

f=open(sys.argv[1]);

for line in f:
    lst=line.split(",")
    for num in lst:
        if(beginning==1):
            sys.stdout.write("if case ")            
            sys.stdout.write(num)
            beginning=0
            prev=num
        else:
            if(num==prev):
                continue;
            else:
                sys.stdout.write("else case ")              
                sys.stdout.write(",")
                sys.stdout.write(num)
                prev=num

    beginning=1
```

Have tried many times to figure our what is wrong, working fine in java.

Comment: You know you can just use `set` to remove duplicates from a list.

Comment: And please do not use semicolons unless for more than 1 statement in the same line!

Comment: Could you please provide testcase where it fails

Comment: python almost never uses semicolons and most definitely does not need them :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

given a file k.txt

k.txt

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 2, 3, 2, 1, 4, 6, 7, 4, 3, 4, 8, 9, 0, 0, 0
```

you can do the following:

```
import numpy as np
# split it in to a list of values and get rid of the newline
a = open('k.txt','r').read().replace('\n','').split(',') 
np.unique(a) # returns unique values and sorts it for you :)
```

why is this better than set?
well:

given a *large* set:

```
a = np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100000))
>>> b = time(); set(a); print time()-b
set([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99])
0.0197851657867
>>> b = time(); np.unique(a); print time()-b
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
       17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33,
       34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50,
       51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67,
       68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84,
       85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99])
0.00981211662292
```

--> faster run times :D

Answer (score 1):

you dont need to do that whole process when you can use `set()`

example:

```
>>> my_list = [1,4,2,3,4,4,3,1,1,5,6,4,3,2]
>>> set(my_list)
set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
>>>
```

`set()` will take all duplicate items out of youre list and leave you with one of each item

read more [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html)